# Window border thickness when changing from Maximized to Normal

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF application, which main window state I want to change from `Maximized` to `Normal`, while keeping actual size. But there is one issue - for some reason (probably default behavior), after switching to `Normal` state, window always gets 1px border thickness. I can fix this by assigning `BorderThickness` property of window manually, right after setting `WindowState` to `Normal`, but it causes visible flickering. Moreover, if moving from Normal back to `Maximized`, and then back to Normal, window still gets border thickness, even if it was set to 0 before.

Is there any way to remove this default behavior for getting border thickness when switching to `Normal`?

Comment: Yes, that's default behavior. And it's not necessarily 1, by the way. Default border width i.e. on Windows 7 is 3 px. Where do you update the property manually?

Comment: I'm trying to update it right after switching WindowState to Normal (as thickness appears only in Normal)

Comment: I mean, where in the code flow. Try updating it in the WindowStateChanged or SizeChanged callbacks.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: Well, yes, this mostly handles issue, now flickering is not visible. I've used StateChanged event.

Comment: Rewritten as answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you directly update the BorderThickness propery inside a callback from changing the window state, like the StateChanged or SizeChanged events. This should remove the flickering.

Hint: You might confuse users with this behavior. Maybe it would be better not to allow maximizing in the first place. Or hide the window frame completelly.